# QXcb Connection

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I'm learning ROS for a college project and I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 off WSL as I'm not allowed to dual-boot my laptop. I don't have a spare machine lying around atm, so I'm running it like this.
Now the problem is that when I run rqt, I'm getting an error stating:

> QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0

On running

> sudo apt-get install ros-lunar-rqt

I am getting:

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
>  Reading
> state information... Done
> ros-lunar-rqt is already the newest
> version
> (0.5.0-0xenial-20171120-112204-0800).
>  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to
> remove and 127 not upgraded.

Any help to get it running would be appreciated!
P.S. I'm running Xming as the X-Server.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278427/qxcb-connection/) by [Lord-Frost](https://answers.ros.org/users/33084/lord-frost/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

before you run that command, initialise Xming, then on Ubuntu type:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

and then run the command.

---

Originally posted by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) with karma: 463 on 2018-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0